# How to validate custom encoded data using @field_validator in Pydatic?

Tags: python, validation, types, pydantic

I am trying to use a custom encoder and decoder in Pydantic (V2). My goal is to convert a reference to another class into its name instead of encoding the whole class and all its children, and resolve it back to the class instance when the JSON is decoded. Example:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, field_validator, ValidationInfo

class B(BaseModel):
    id: str
    value: int

class A(BaseModel):
    id: str
    ref: B

    class Config:
        json_encoders = {
            B: lambda t: f'{t.id}',
        }
    
    @classmethod
    @field_validator("ref", mode="before")
    def map_ref(cls, v: str, info: ValidationInfo) -> B:
        return Bs[v]

b1 = B(id="B1", value=1)
b2 = B(id="B2", value=2)
Bs = { "B1" : b1, "B2" : b2}

a1 = A(id="A1", ref=b1)
a1d = a1.model_dump_json()
print("JSON: ", a1d)

a1r = A.model_validate_json(a1d)
print("Recon: ", a1r)
```

The output is:

```
JSON:  {"id":"A1","ref":"B1"}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Projects\2022 NeoCity MeDT\medtproofofconcept\AppServer\custom_deserialize_test.py", line 29, in <module>
    a1r = A.model_validate_json(a1d)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Projects\2022 NeoCity MeDT\medtproofofconcept\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pydantic\main.py", line 531, in model_validate_json
    return cls.__pydantic_validator__.validate_json(json_data, strict=strict, context=context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 1 validation error for A
ref
  Input should be an object [type=model_type, input_value='B1', input_type=str]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.3/v/model_type
```

So the encoding works, instead of the whole model it only prints the `id`. But the decoding throws an error, and when I debug it my custom validator is never called, even though it is marked to run `before` internal validation.

What am I doing wrong? Any hints welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Your code fails because you swapped the order of the `classmethod` and the `field_validator`. The `classmethod` should be the inner decorator. In addition you need to adapt the validator to allow for an instance of `B` as well:

```py
    @field_validator("ref", mode="before")
    @classmethod
    def map_ref(cls, v: str, info: ValidationInfo) -> B:
        if isinstance(v, B):
            return v
        return Bs[v]
```

However I would argue you rather might want to work with a discriminated union here:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel,  model_serializer, Field
from typing import Annotated, Union, Literal

class B(BaseModel):
    id: str

    @model_serializer()
    def serialize(self) -> str:
        return {"id": self.id}

class B1(B):
    id: Literal["B1"] = "B1"
    value: int = 1
    

class B2(B):
    id:  Literal["B2"] = "B2"
    value: int = 2


class A(BaseModel):
    id: str
    ref: Annotated[Union[B1, B2], Field(discriminator="id")]


a1 = A(id="A1", ref=B1())
a1d = a1.model_dump_json()
print("JSON: ", a1d)

a1r = A.model_validate_json(a1d)
print("Recon: ", a1r)
```

Which prints:

```
JSON:  {"id":"A1","ref":{"id":"B1"}}
Recon:  id='A1' ref=B1(id='B1', value=1)
```

So instead of handling different instances of `B` you work with subclasses of `B` with different default values.

You can find more about discriminated unions here: https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/unions/#discriminated-unions

I hope this helps!

Comment: That could work in some cases, but not in all, some are more dynamic than subclasses. I think I found the problem though: `@classmethod` needs to come after the `@field_validator`. Putting together an example to post here in a bit.